# Avoid refresh android scrollview elements

Tags: android, refresh, scrollview

I have a Listview with inside some elements (a button and an edittext). I was able to disable the button after the first click on it. My problem is that if I scroll the list, and then return upside, my button is again enabled. While i'd like that It will not change his state if I don't change activity.

So I think that there is a kind of refresh when you scroll the list....how can I avoid this??

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

[Example something what you want](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)